# Understanding Deis Clusters usage

Tags: deis

I'm starting with Deis, and would like to understand the way clusters are meant to work.

The local vagrant environment example provisions a 3 server coreOS cluster and deploy the platform itself to this cluster, and then creates a dev cluster on this same group of hosts, therefore sharing the same servers with the platform.

In a prod or QA env, should a different CoreOS cluster be provisioned and then a Deis cluster created on this new group of servers? Is this possible/good practice?

If I have 3 envs, dev/qa/prod, Should I create 3 Deis clusters on 3 different CoreOS clusters? What would be the workflow for passing a release to QA/Prod? Pushing to different git remotes, creating the same app in the three Deis clusters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of Deis, a `Cluster` is equivalent to a CoreOS cluster for scheduling apps. This model has been proven to be too confusing for end users, so we are planning on removing it. You can view the proposal here: https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/2007